# Atribuir comando execute a uma variável

Tags: sql, sql-server, procedure, cursor

Preciso que o retorno do comando execute seja atribuído a variável @PAGO pois vou inseri-lo em uma tabela temporária só que o que retorna é o script e não o valor.

```
DECLARE @COMANDO_COMANDO_PAGO VARCHAR(2000)
   SET @SITUACAO = 'PAGO'
    SET @COMANDO_COMANDO_PAGO = 'select  count(f.matricula)
    from matricula m
        inner join aluno a
    on a.matricula = m.matricula
        inner join financeiro f
    on m.matricula = f.matricula
        and m.ano = f.ano and m.semestre = f.semestre and m.periodo = f.periodo
    where m.ano = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ANO) + ' and m.semestre = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@SEMESTRE) + '

EXEC(@COMANDO_COMANDO_PAGO)
SET @PAGO = @COMANDO_COMANDO_PAGO
```

tabela temporária

```
INSERT INTO #temp_finc VALUES (@PERIODO,@PAGO,@EM_ABERTA)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pra usar assim, você precisa fazer sua query dinâmica admitir um valor de retorno. Algo assim:

```
SET @COMANDO_COMANDO_PAGO = 'select @Pago = count(f.matricula)
from matricula m
    inner join aluno a
on a.matricula = m.matricula
    inner join financeiro f
on m.matricula = f.matricula
    and m.ano = f.ano and m.semestre = f.semestre and m.periodo = f.periodo
where m.ano = @ANO and m.semestre = @SEMESTRE'
```

E então executar com o [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) da seguinte forma:

```
SET @ParamDefinition = N'@ANO varchar, @SEMESTRE varchar, @Pago int OUTPUT';
EXEC sp_executesql @COMANDO_COMANDO_PAGO, @ParamDefinition, @ANO=CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ANO), @SEMESTRE=CONVERT(VARCHAR,@SEMESTRE), @Pago=@Pago OUTPUT;
```